# Passing Javascript (HTML Table Contents) array to php file

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Im very confused, I have been looking for a solution to pass HTML table contents via a javascript array (if this is indeed the best way of capturing HTML Table data) to a php file so I can then do whatever I like with the data.

I have simplified the table shown in my example code in order to make it easier, the table i will be using live will have a lot of rows with more complicated data etc.

The current code in get_table_data_php is:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<div id ="results_table">
    <table id="stats_table">
        <tr>
            <td>Car</td><td>Engine</td><td>Color</td><td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ford</td><td>2 Litre</td><td>Blue</td><td>22,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Audi</td><td>2.5 Litre</td><td>White</td><td>25,000</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div> 


<script>
var myTableArray = [];
$("table#stats_table tr").each(function() { 
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
    if (tableData.length > 0) {
        tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
        myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }
});

alert(myTableArray); // alerts the entire array

alert(myTableArray[0][0]); // Alerts the first tabledata of the first tablerow

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: {myTableArray:myTableArray},
   url: "stats.php",
   success: function(msg){
     $('.answer').html(msg);
   }
});


</script>
```

The code in the stats.php file being called is as follows:-

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

The code in the calling php file runs as expected and shows (via the alert(s) which are there for my sanity)  the table data as expected.

The file called (stats.php) however does not do anything and as such I do not know if its working and what the issue is as to why it isn't.

I am pretty new to the Javascript and Ajax side of things so any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Alan

Comment: First of all, change .answers to a id instead of a class, because your result element needs to be just one. To check wheter your Ajax returns, add the code alert(msg) inside your success callback.

Comment: Hi Marco, sorry for being such a novice but can you please expand upon your response regarding "change .answers to a id instead of a class, because your result element needs to be just one"

I'm not sure i understand what I need to change in the code!!

Thanks for getting back to me so quickly though.

Regards

Alan

Comment: From the example that you gave, you are injecting the response of the Ajax on any element with a class named answer (the dot(.) implies is a class. See CSS selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors). Insert the alert as i told you, so you can read Ajax response.

Comment: Hi Marco,
I think we may have crossed wires here unless i'm mistaken. 
The values in the table cells are not related to CSS.
for example if the table was as follows

<div id ="results_table">
    <table id="stats_table">
        <tr>
            <td>Car</td><td>Engine</td><td>Size</td><td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ford</td><td>Petrol</td><td>2 Litre</td><td>£17,000</td>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div> 
I would want to pass the cell values to a php file and use the values in the php file that was called.

Alan

Comment: Yes you are mistaken, CSS selectors are used to filter HTML elements and then do something with them, thats exactly what you want :)

Example: $('#results_table td') retrieves all td's on table with id results_table got it?